# display progress bar when file download in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have one model popup with list of pdf file for download. i want to display progressbar for each pdf file during downloading.
I'm working on mvc 4 project and open model popup via jQuery. 
How it is possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's already a progress bar in the lower left corner of your browser when downloading a file. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

a download progress bar is done simular to an upload. you will need a custom handler that does not use buffered responses. it should do a write and flush, and maintain a output status in a static variable (usually a collection with a download key). a non-session based web service is supported to check the download status (total bytes/ bytes sent).  now client side javascript makes the download request (target an iframe or new window) passing the download key, then starts polling the server to get the status. with the status it can update a progress bar.